# Prove that $f(x)=(1-x^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ is concave down on the interval $[0,1 ]$ if $p\in (1, \infty).$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am thinking to prove this question by the definition of concave down. But then it involves an inequality that is out of my scope of learning. So I am wondering is there any other elementary way to prove it. Or maybe I should really learn Hölder's inequality to solve this problem.

Comment: Where does the variable $t $ involve.

Comment: Sorry a typo, because I thought later I will use a point, say t $\in (0,1)$ to make an inequality to prove that the graph concave down on the interval [0,1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=(1-x^p)^{1/p}$ is a $C^\infty(0,1)$ function, hence it is enough to prove $f''(x)<0$ for any $x\in(0,1)$. By a straightforward computation:

$$ f''(x) = x^{p-2}f(x)\cdot\frac{1-p}{(1-x^p)^2} < 0 $$
and the concavity of $f(x)$ follows.

There probably is some tricky equivalent approach exploiting the fact that $f(x)$ is an involutive map, i.e. $f(f(x))=x$, from which $f'(x)\,f'(f(x))=1$.

Comment: But this question is asking for the concavity of $f$ on $[0,1]$, not $(0,1)$. I think an addtional proof by contradiction is required.

Answer (score 1):

A smooth function is concave iff its second derivative is nonpositive. Therfore in you question, Just compute $f''$ and see on where it is nonpositive.

Answer (score 0):

**little hint**

Write $f (x)=e^{\frac {1}{p}\ln (1-x^p)} $
and compute

$f'(x) $ and may be $f''(x) $.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly, and following right from the definition: a concave and increasing function of a concave function is concave. That's the situation we have here, with the first function being $x\to x^{1/p},$ and the second function being $x\to 1-x^p.$